# md5sum change when modifying comments in msg/srv/action?

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When only updating comments in `.msg/.srv/.action` file, does checksum get changed?

Locally I tested as follows and md5 doesn't seem to change.

Here's from DEB:

```
$ rospack find moveit_msgs
/opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_msgs
$ rossrv md5 ExecuteKnownTrajectory
[moveit_msgs/ExecuteKnownTrajectory]: e30b86cbd13304832e894dc994795e33
$ rosversion moveit_msgs
0.7.4
$ dpkg -p ros-indigo-moveit-msgs|grep Ver
Version: 0.7.4-0trusty-20160822-230048-0700
```

Then I modified comment only in ExecuteKnownTrajectory.srv (using [this PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_msgs/pull/29)):

```
$ cd src/ros-planning/moveit_msgs
$ git log
commit 2807deaf572d19793e825c39453fc7337d68e749
Author: Isaac I.Y. Saito <130s@2000.jukuin.keio.ac.jp>
Date:   Mon Aug 29 17:34:11 2016 -0700

    Add comment in ExecuteKnownTrajectory service to prioritize newly added ExecuteTrajectory action.
:
$ catkin build moveit_msgs
$ source install/setup.bash
$ rospack find moveit_msgs
/home/rosnoodle/indigo_trusty/cws_planning/install/share/moveit_msgs
$ rossrv md5 ExecuteKnownTrajectory
[moveit_msgs/ExecuteKnownTrajectory]: e30b86cbd13304832e894dc994795e33
```

md5sum seems to be the same.

IMO comment is the best place for description of those files so I hope the answer to be false.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242722/md5sum-change-when-modifying-comments-in-msg/srv/action?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-30**:
I'm confused: you are actually asking for confirmation whether the comment is **not** used when calculating the MD5 sum, correct?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-08-30**:
@gvdhoorn Yes, that's correct. And I escalated one of your comments as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [wiki/ROS - Technical Overview - Message serialization and msg MD5 sums](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Message_serialization_and_msg_MD5_sums) comments should not be part of the *MD5 text*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0